# Android - Admob rewarded ads automatically disappear after some time

Tags: java, android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I had placed admob rewarded ads on my app. Whenever rewarded ads starts and after some time it tend to disappear automatically without taking any user action. Do help me out on how I can resolve the issue?